# How to prove finite sets are countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This textbook definition seems to define "countable" to be "infinitely countable".

[image]

Are there any ways to use these definitions to prove that finite sets are countable?

Comment: The definitions there are pretty explicit:  finite sets are finite, and countable sets are infinite.  Under these definitions, you cannot prove that a finite set is countable, because it is *by definition* not countable.

Comment: Not if you use this books definition.  In this book, countable seems to mean infinitely countable and therefore finite sets are by (this books) definition are not countable.  But... so what... that's one books definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Under these definitions, finite sets are not countable.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected the answer is "No", but was not sure.

Comment: But it's only *this* book's definitions.  *MANY* other books will define countable to include finite.

Comment: @ensbana: It is important to point out that in many places "countable" includes finite, and in many places it is excluded. This is really context dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sim$ means there is an injection from the left set into the right set, then $A$ finite does in fact imply $A$ is countable by this definition.

Comment: Do you really think the book uses ~ to mean injection?  And not bijection.

Comment: It actually uses ~ to mean bijection.

Comment: I doubt it (reply to first commenter) but I’m not aware of any texts that do not include finite sets to be in the class of countable sets.  That’s why I said “If...”

Comment: I've known a few.  This book could be doing so but made an oversight.  But we could call a finite set "turkey dinner" for all any *actual* difference in math it would make.

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches:

1) Some texts define "countable" as *either* finite or in one-to-one bijection to $\mathbb N$ (which this book calls $\mathbb J$).  In which case you can't prove finite sets are countable because they are countable by definition.

2) Other text define $A$ being  "countable" as there being an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$.  In that case you can prove a finite set is countable.

3) *THIS* book defines "countable" as being in bijection to $\mathbb N$.  In which case you can't prove finite sets are countable because by (this) definition they are not countable.

....

Definitions are definitions.  They aren't universal truths.  If you called a dog's tail a leg, it'd have five legs but it couldn't walk on all of them.

Comment: That was a typo.  That was *exactly* what I meant to say.

Comment: I) and 2) finite sets are countable: 1) by definition (not proof) and 2) by proof.  3) finite sets are not countable.  (Which IMO I find irksome.)